How to apply simple lemma with complex instantiation in Coq?
I have a goal that looks like (A <-> B) -> ~A with complex expressions A and B, and I want my goal to become ~B.
I tried creating a simple Lemma that (A <-> B) -> ~A -> ~B
Section Test.
Variables A B C : Prop.

Lemma eq1 : (A <-> B) -> ~A -> ~B.
intros H_iff not_A.
assert (B -> A).
rewrite H_iff.
auto.
auto.
Qed.

But when I try to apply it in my proof like this
pose proof (Test.eq1 (ATK (S t_N)) _).

where t_N: nat, ATK: nat -> Prop.
It complains
The term "ATK (S t_N)" has type "Prop" while it is expected to have type
 "A <-> B".

So I am assuming I am doing something wrong in defining eq1, but I don't know what, since I am completely new to Coq.

You should look into implicit arguments. Also consider asking on Proof Assistants SE.

Two problems. 1. You seem to be confusing ((A <-> B) -> ~A) -> ~B with (A <-> B) -> (~A -> ~B). These expressions are not  the same, nor are they even logically equivalent in general. (Implication is not associative.) (A <-> B) -> ~A -> ~B by itself means (A <-> B) -> (~A -> ~B). 2. If your goal says X, and your lemma says X -> Y, you cannot apply this lemma towards this goal. (It is logically invalid to attempt such an application.) In order to apply an implication to a goal, you need a goal X and a lemma Y -> X. Alternatively, X <-> Y can be applied towards a goal of X.
